# Endosymbiosis Probability

Tags: molecular-biology

What is the probability of endosymbiosis occurring? I remember seeing it in my AP Biology textbook but haven't been able to find it anywhere after forgetting it. I want to say I remember it being something like 1e-40 but can't say for sure. Also, I'm not a biology student so I'm not sure if endosymbiosis is the proper term for it but I think what I'm referring to is the successful absorption of a prokaryote by an organism to become a eukaryotic organism with mitochondrion.

Comment: According to endosymbiotic theory, the probability on Earth is 1. It's not really meaningful or useful to estimate probabilities of one seemingly unlikely thing that you have evidence has occurred. What do you hope to do with this probability?

Comment: You are going to want to look up endosymbiosis and algae for lots of examples of the spectrum of endosymbiosis .

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is unclear (or unanswerable due to not making sense), and lacks the expected level of prior research. Please note these are both sufficient reasons for downvoting and closure. Please [edit] your question and tell us: what your question is, where you've looked for answers, what you *do* know about the topic, and where exactly you still have questions. Please take the [tour] and consult the [help] starting with [ask] for details.